# Who or what were the Lord Relictors?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

I've recently read The Gates of Azyr and it discusses many of the Stormcast Eternal's previous lives, it talks about Vandus before he was reborn however it only hints there's more to the Lord Relictors than meets the eye. Certainly Ionus Cryptborn is very mysterious.

Is there any official on who or what the Lord Relictors were before they were resurrected? Were they necromancers? Vampires?

Answer (score 3):

We know at least that only undead warriors can be Relictors, as Sigmar gathers them exclusively from the [Realm of Shyish (death)](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Mortal_Realms#Shyish.2C_the_Realm_of_Death) where [Nagash](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Nagash) is in charge.

After that, it's purely speculation as to who is who.

I reckon Ionus will turn out to be [Settra the Imperishable](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Settra) or [Arkhan the Black](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Arkhan), but that's just a guess on my part.